# protractor-js setting form action attributes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-e2e, protractor

I have today tried to send the data via a form but the data must go in a post uri, Is there a way of appending the params to the form uri in a view which I could then submit a click to.

I have tried the code below. However,

`driver.findElement(protractor.By.name('formelement')).setAttribute('action', attr);`

returns Object has no method setAttribute

```
driver.findElement(protractor.By.name('externalFormData')).getText().then(function(result){
    var attr = driver.findElement(proractor.By.name('formelement').getAttribute('action');
    attr += result;
    driver.findElement(protractor.By.name('formelement')).setAttribute('action', attr);
    driver.findElement(protractor.By.name('submitRequest')).click();
});
```

Comment: I don't have an answer for your question sorry. However, your question did help me out with getting at a field, so thanks for that! I needed to do .getAttribute('value') to get at the data I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Julie Ralph, the lead developer on protractor says its not (natively) possible here:

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/82

juliemr commented on Sep 12, 2013
A user wouldn't set an attribute, so it's not a feature of webdriver. Can you find a way of running your test manually just using your page? It seems that you might have to use angular and $http.post() instead of just relying on the 's action attribute.

Personally, this stinks a little. I have tests timing out because sendKeys is so slow on long text files. I'll keep you updated if I find a good work-around. Maybe there needs to be a 'pasteTextBlock' instead of 'sendKeys' ... by Julie's rationale a user might copy and paste rather than key in...

Comment: Yeah I think I managed to answer my own question on that link. But I'll give you credit for the link and the updated answer as I forgot to update stackoverflow